# Can't delete PDF files programmatically

Tags: c#, pdf

I can't delete a pdf file from a shared drive (Windows mapped drive) from my c# Winform desktop program which runs on Windows 10 OS. The pdf file was created by Crystal Report in my c# program and when there is a revision, I need to delete the old pdf file and write the new one. I will get access denied error (HResult=0x80070005) when the program tries to delete the file. This only happens when the I try to delete it from a shared drive. If I generate the pdf file in the local drive (c:), and delete it from the local drive, then everything is find. I can manually delete the pdf file from File Explorer, but not from my c# program.

In addition, if the file is not a pdf file, then there is no problem to delete it from the shared drive.

It is weird that this only happens to pdf file or a file with .pdf extension. If I create a simple text file (test.txt) with C++ and save it in the shared drive, I can delete it without any problem. But when I create the same text file and name it as test.pdf, then I can't delete it.

HResult=0x80070005 seems only links to permission issue, but I strongly believe my case is NOT a permission issue because if the file is *.txt, then I can always delete it without any issues.

To rule out the possibility of the pdf file that may be still linked with the Crystal Report or opened by some programs, I copied the pdf file from the shared drive and save it in my local drive (c:) and wrote a simple c++ program to test if I can delete it, and it failed. Can't delete it. I can only delete it if the pdf file was created and saved in the local drive originally. And if the pdf file is copied from the shared drive to the local drive, then I can't delete it.

I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: Is it being indexed by some other system?

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) FTW.

Comment: Can you delete the PDF file on the share manually (in Windows Explorer)?

Comment: Yes, I can delete the pdf file manually

Comment: somethings happen when a file is created with .pdf extension

Comment: You sure it's not read-only?

Answer (score 2):

**I think (you/your app) don't Have Permission To Delete a File**

- Go to the folder that contains the PDF File.
- Right-click on that folder and choose Properties.
- Navigate to the Security tab.
- Click on Edit, then click Add.
- Under the Enter the object names to select box. Type
  "Everyone"(without quotes) and click on Check names. Click OK.
- A new window will open up with the Security tab. Under Permissions for
  Everyone, check the Full control option. Select Apply and OK.
- Ownership is already allowed for the folder.
- Now you Can delete PDF files programmatically

[Don't Have Permission To Delete a Folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dont-have-permission-to-delete-a-folder/6e2523b7-50f5-47cf-9edc-f06d68d9ef43)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying to provide solutions for this problem. With a help from a friend, I finally found the root cause of the problem. It is the Norton antivirus that prevents me from deleting a certain types of files. .pdf is one of them. After I unchecked the .pdf from Norton, it works like a magic.

It is the antivirus program that prevents me from deleting .pdf file programmatically.